# How to add OFFICE 365 SHAREPOINT ONLINE Permission to a microsoft Application?

Tags: permissions, office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, office365-apps

I have created two applications in a microsoft office 365 account. When I saw the permission details for these two apps, I found one difference. For the first application, "OFFICE 365 SHAREPOINT ONLINE" was present, on the other hand it was absent in case of second app.

Can someone please explain why it was present in first application but absent in second one?

Also how to add the missing permission "OFFICE 365 SHAREPOINT ONLINE" for an application?

[Sharepoint online Permission in first application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pD5g.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks in your screenshot like you're looking at the Enterprise Apps blade.  I believe that will only show the permissions that the app has actually requested.

To change which permissions show up there you'll actually need to change the permissions being requested by the app which would happen under either the App Registrations or App Registrations (Preview) blade (slightly farther down in the list where you already are) depending on where you originally registered the app.

You should only need SharePoint permissions directly though if you plan to call SharePoint APIs that aren't covered by Microsoft Graph.  You can do many tasks in Microsoft Graph directly so make sure you actually need the SharePoint permissions before requesting them.